# Regex not limiting values after decimal point

Tags: javascript, regex

My text field should accept values between 0.00 and 0.99 and I have the following regex

```
^0.\.*[0,9]{0,2}$
```

But its not limiting the values after decimal point.Can someone guide me to fix it.

Comment: I recommend using a site like https://regex101.com/ for easy debugging of regex.

Comment: `^0\.[0-9]{0,2}$`

Comment: @Our_Benefactors beat me by 30s. I was going to recommend http://www.regextester.com/

Answer (score 0):

The correct code for that is

```
^0\.[0-9]{1,2}$
```

The errors in your expression are that

1) `[0,9]` is not a range. It means that the characters `0`, `,`and `9` can be matched at the end of the string.

2)`0.\.*` means that any single-character may be matched if it comes after a `0` and before a `dot`. Including alphabetic characters.

To debug in an easier way, try online testers, such as http://www.regextester.com/

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
^0\.\d{0,2}$
```

- `^` Look for start of line
- `0\.` Look for `0.`
- `\d{0,2}` Look for a digit between 0 and 2 times
- `$` Look for end of line